# I have a wordpress website which uses a really weird font on Opera. What do I need to do to fix it?

Tags: css, fonts

I have a website which gets this font:

[image]

when shown in Opera. Other websites work just fine and that very website works just fine in Firefox and Chrome.

Is there something improperly setup in my Wordpress website?

Notes:

- I'm using the default **Twenty Twenty-One** theme with small tweaks, but not in link with the fonts at first;
- Now I force "sans-serif", but I still see the issue with Opera...

Answer (score 0):

Now there is a weird one...

I killed and then restarted Opera and things are fixed. It works as expected. No funky font. This is not the answer I expected, though.